# Error when attempting to run detox test with xcodebuild created .app file

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm trying to create a `.app` that I can then reference in my `.detoxrc.json` file but I'm running into 2 issues.

This is the command I'm using...

`xcodebuild -workspace ios/Boomin.xcworkspace -scheme Boomin -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build -UseModernBuildSystem=YES -arch x86_64`

1. The only `.app` file I can see is created in the `ios -> build -> Build -> Products -> Debug-iphonesimulator` directory and it's called `customer.app`. It looks like `customer` comes from my terminal user account. How do I rename this?
2. When I try to run `detox test --configuration ios` I get the following...

`detox[19353] ERROR: field CFBundleIdentifier not found inside Info.plist of app binary at /ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/customer.app`

How do I resolve both these issues?

Thanks,